# Why did my index become unusable after setting MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I run Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0, and followed [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321) to set MAX_STRING_SIZE to EXTENDED, to be allowed to use more than 4000 bytes in a VARCHAR2 column.

Running the utl32k.sql script produced two warnings:

```
Index "SCHEMA"."T01CALENDAR_CATEGORY" must be dropped because it now exceeds maximum key length.
Index "SCHEMA"."SYS_C007463" must be dropped because it now exceeds maximum key length.
```

This is surprising to me, because the column definition hasn't changed:

```
SQL> desc t01calendar
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PROJID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 CATEGORY                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
 START_DATE                NOT NULL DATE
 END_DATE                  NOT NULL DATE
```

And T01CALENDAR_CATEGORY is simply an index created by:

```
CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."T01CALENDAR_CATEGORY" ON "SCHEMA"."T01CALENDAR" ("PROJID", "CATEGORY")
```

Why did this index suddenly become unusable, and do I have to drop it, or is there some other way to have an index on a VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) column?

Comment: It depends on the block size of your DB. for an 8k block size, you're restricted till 6398 bytes. And one more important thing,  new MAX_STRING_SIZE can be EXTENDED to 32767, but behind scene, Oracle still uses LOB to store such big data.

Comment: If you use double byte or UTF8 encoding then 4000 char will exceed the index size - independent of the MAX_STRING_SIZE setting.

Comment: Why is `CATEGORY ` so big?